# How to capture integer value from JSON input in spring?

Tags: java, json, spring

In my spring project, I am getting all input values in JSON format.

```
@ResponseBody UserDto userDto
```

The `ResponseBody` annotation is good to capture data. But how can I achieve something as follows?

```
@ResponseBody String userId;
```

While writing the above code userId is not getting. Is there any other annotation available to capture single value without using a wrapper? or can I create a custom functionality myself to achieve this?

Any suggestions will be useful.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code here to understand the problem you're trying to solve, nor have you indicated what kind of "exception is occurring". As it's currently written, your question doesn't really have enough detail to provide a useful answer. Please add additional details to your post to clarify your issue.

Comment: sorry bro i will update my question keep in touch

Comment: Please add your code snippet as well as error in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this approach as is, you'll just need to modify your input data:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So45583717Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So45583717Application.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public static class Ctrl {

        @PostMapping
        public String post(@RequestBody Integer userId) {
            return "UserId is: " + userId;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:8080' -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d'42'
UserId is: 42%
```

In case you want to pass something like `{ "userId": 42 }` you'll need a wrapper object in order serialization to work.

**EDIT**

And another way of doing this is to accept raw string as a body and do extraction work by yourself:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public static class Ctrl {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @PostMapping
    public String post(@RequestBody String body) throws IOException {
        final JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(body);
        return "UserId is: " + jsonNode.findValue("userId");
    }
}
```

Example:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:8080' -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"userId": 42}'
UserId is: 42%
```

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token what is this?

Comment: @jishnuradhakrishnan please show your input data and method signature

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/dataLoad",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public void dataLoad(@RequestBody String userName) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException{
  System.out.println("data captured>>>>>>>>>>>"+userName);
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(userName);
  userName=jsonNode.findValue("userName").toString();
  System.out.println("user name is >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+userName);
  
 }

Comment: @jishnuradhakrishnan please show your input data as well. Your code is correct, for `curl -XPOST 'localhost:8080/dataLoad' -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"userName": "John"}'` it prints `data captured>>>>>>>>>>>{"userName": "John"}` and `user name is >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"John"`

Comment: {"userName":"adam"} and content type is set to application/json